# Date formatting error when importing dates stored as text

Tags: excel, date-formatting, vba

I have a simple macro (as part of a whole bunch of others in my workbook) that copies the contents of a column in one worksheet into another. This column is a bunch of dates which are stored as text. The issue is, for all dates less that the 12th of the month, it's appropriating the the day as the month and vice versa.

There is a bunch of similar topics on here and other sites but none of them have really worked. I hoping there is a simple fix.

**My recent version of the macro**

```
Sub DateMacro()

Sheets("Output").Range("A2:A1048575").NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
Sheets("Input").Range("A2:A1048575").NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
Sheets("Output").Range("A2:A1048575").Value = Sheets("Input").Range("A2:A1048575").Value

End Sub
```

I've linked a sample workbook [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q5F6mgEzVgrc1nyDzTFcF29FQWxH6VsV)

Additional info:
I don't have control about how the dates are formatted when exported from my reporting system so I need to make the changes within my reporting workbook.

Update: I spoke to a colleague and he came up with this:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim RngEnd As Long

Dim rng As String
Dim test As String

RngEnd = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To RngEnd

rng = "A" & i
test = Sheets("Input").Range(rng).Value

Sheets("Output").Range(rng) = DateValue(test) + TimeValue(test)


Next i
End Sub
```

This appears to work fine but there is a popup with "Error 13 Type Mismatch". Any idea or amendments to this one that you can think of?

Comment: Apologies, but can't open the file : `Sorry, we can't open your workbook in Excel Online because it exceeds the 5 MB file size limit.` Can you just paste a sample format or a screenshot atleast?And what exactly is the error?

Comment: Additionally, you can also simplify `.Range("A2:A1048575")` to `.Range("A:A")`

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the link with an Excel file. I don't know why saving it as .xlsm and including the above macro blows the file size out to 11MB. You just need t copy the above code and run.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each cell, check if the day is within 1 to 12, and then switch the day and month using `DateSerial`. Then store it in an array (to run faster), and at the end, dump the entire array to "output" sheet using `Application.Transpose`.

More explanation inside the code's comments.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub DateMacro()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim DateStr As String
Dim DatesArr() As Double

ReDim DatesArr(0)

With Sheets("Input")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column A

    For i = 2 To LastRow ' from 2nd row until last row with data
        ' === if day  is from 1 though 12 of the month comes "mm/dd/yyyy" >> switch month and day ===
        Select Case Day(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            Case 1 To 12
                DateStr = Format(.Range("A" & i).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")

                ' switch month and day
                DatesArr(UBound(DatesArr)) = DateSerial(Year(DateValue(DateStr)), Day(DateValue(DateStr)), Month(DateValue(DateStr)))

            Case Else
                DatesArr(UBound(DatesArr)) = DateValue(.Range("A" & i).Value)

        End Select

        ReDim Preserve DatesArr(UBound(DatesArr) + 1) ' keep record and raise array index by 1
    Next i
End With

' resize array to actual populated size
ReDim Preserve DatesArr((UBound(DatesArr) - 1))

Sheets("Output").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"

' use Application.Transpose to copy the entire array contents to your range
Sheets("Output").Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value = Application.Transpose(DatesArr)

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That didn't work. It pasted the dates but hasn't re-formatted them. As I've mentioned to the above comment, I've updated the link to the sample document if you want to give it a crack yourself

Comment: It it because the cells are formatted as text?
Edit: Nevermind, they input cells are formatting as custom and the output are formatted as general.

Answer (score 1):

I've found something that works in my case. Just posting in case anyone else needs it. I just need to format the Output range as Text before transferring the data and then convert it back into the date format I want.

```
Sheets("Output").Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets("Input").Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
Sheets("Output").Range("A:A").Value = Sheets("Input").Range("A:A").Value
Sheets("Output").Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "d/mm/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
```

Thanks to everyone else for their time/input